# Best way to store the values from different Form - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to store the values from different Form to a global object and retrieve later using React js. I have nearly 5 to 10 individual pop-up forms. What is the best way

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The purpose of why you need to access this form data globally should drive this decision, but one option is to use a [closure](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp). It is basically a private object that sits in the global namespace, that can be updated from anywhere in your app.

This will allow you to set, or access your form data, from anywhere in your React app, as long as your application(browser window) lives. If you need to persist this beyond the browser session, then I would use something like `localStorage`.

Here is a simple example:

```
// FormData.js
var FormData = (function() {
  var someData = {};

  var getSomeData = function() {
    return someData;
  };

  var setSomeData = function(someData) {
    someData = JSON.parse(someData);
  };

  return {
    getSomeData: getSomeData,
    setSomeData: setSomeData
  }
})();

export default FormData;
```

All you have to do is `import` this js file when you want to **get** or **set** the form data.

**Get** the form data with ...

```
import FormData from '/FormData';
var someData = FormData.getSomeData();
```

**Set** the form data with ...

```
import FormData from '/FormData';
FormData.setSomeData(newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not specifying the details, reasons or purposes for storing such objects, the easiest way to store them would be to use localStorage API, so you could retrieve them during the session and after the page is reloaded:

```
localStorage.setItem('form1', JSON.stringify(formData));
const form1Data = localStorage.getItem('form1');
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.